# Cassandra RPC TimeOut on Secondary Index

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We are getting rpc_timeout when running query on a secondary index in cassandra.

The Secondary Index column holds only 2 values, either 'true' or 'false'.
There query has pagination build in, to limit the number of records returned
Here is the Query

```
Select id_firm, id_uuid from efstatus where isFinal='true' and TOKEN(id_firm) >= TOKEN(99625490-29b4-4474-a731-9b7664f642f8) LIMIT 25;
```

This is the Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE efstatus (
  id_firm uuid,
  id_uuid uuid,
  isfinal text,
  json_data text,
  type text,
  year text,
 PRIMARY KEY (id_firm, id_uuid)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};

CREATE INDEX efstatus_isfinal ON efstatus (isfinal);

CREATE INDEX efstatus_year ON efstatus (year);
```

Running Trace ON gives no relevant information. This is what I see

```
Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

We are using DataStax version 3.1.4, which has I believe Cassandra v 1.2.10.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html <- note: "creating an index on an extremely low-cardinality column, such as a boolean column, does not make sense. Each value in the index becomes a single row in the index, resulting in a huge row for all the false values, for example. Indexing a multitude of indexed columns having foo = true and foo = false is not useful."

Comment: While @stinkymatt's comment is generally true, it's not always true. Indexing boolean columns is pretty useful when you're dealing with a small data set. 

If you have two rows (true/false respectively) with a few thousand records in them each, anyone at DataStax who tells you to rewrite your schema because this 2i is non-performant isn't capable of thinking critically. When you're dealing with millions of records however, they're right: you'll need to refactor.

I'm troubleshooting this very issue at the moment in DSE 4.0 (C* 2.0) with a 2i that has < 50 records. Will let you know.

Comment: stinkymatt fully endorses @Aaronontheweb's qualification. It's a very good point.